# Google map in android

Tags: android-manifest

I am trying to make simple google map Application in android.
 my Apps. is run fine but it doesn,t show google map, it just show grid on screen.
 i also obtain google API key for map..
 Any help?

Thanks.

My Menifest file.

Comment: Can you post Logcat Output and AndroidManifest.xml file code so that we can come to know easily whats the exact problem ?

Comment: have you generated MPI key using http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html  ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a very FAQ:

1. [Google map in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273797/google-map-in-android)
2. [How to show a map in an Android mapactivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097594/how-to-show-a-map-in-an-android-mapactivity)

Comment: i have done all, give INTERNET permission, uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps", generate API key but i still can't see Google Map on Device or Emulator.

Comment: Did you set the API key in your XML (for the google maps view)? Did you read the parts about application signing?

Comment: Is your phone & emulator connected to the internet?

Comment: yes. my emulator is connected to internet And phone is connected to WI-FI.

Comment: Finally i see the log cat And it shows---> 11-25 12:26:58.554: DEBUG/SntpClient(58): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you've declared

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

inside the application tag?