# why show only gridline in google map?

Tags: android

I am developing Google map in my application but its not showing map only showing grid line ,Please anyone help me what is problem is that?
                                              And I am drawing text over bubbles,when more than 2 bubble lie same places,in that case text overlapping to each other.
                                                                          After changing API key Map will be showing but my second problem still remaining.I have to draw bubbles on Map and text (size of property on that bubble) suppose there are size of list 4 then 4 should be draw on bubble.I have been implemented these but there is no desire output is showing.
                                                                                     When more than 2 property on same position and each have more than 2 list size then text on bubble overlapp to eachother sorry for my explanation I am using this code -

```
            drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bluedot);
            drawable1 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bluedot_large);

             overlay = new GoogleMapViewOverlay(drawable,mapView,activity);
```

//GoogleMapViewOverlay method is as:-

```
public GoogleMapViewOverlay(Drawable drawable, MapView mapView,
            Activity activity2)
    {
        //super(drawable);
        super(boundCenterBottom(drawable));
        setLastFocusedIndex(-1);
        populate();         
        arrayList1  = new ArrayList<Applicationdataset>() ;
        items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
        marker = drawable;
        mContext = mapView.getContext();
        mc = mapView.getController();
        this.activity = activity2;
        DB = new DatabaseHelper(activity2);
    }
```

//add item as

```
if(point != null)
                        {
                            if(arrayList.get(i).getUnitstotal().equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                            {  
                                oi = overlay.createItem(i);
                                System.out.println("listing when 1 value is"+arrayList.get(i).getUnitstotal());
                                overlay.addItem(oi);
                            }
                            else if(!arrayList.get(i).getUnitstotal().equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                            {
                                oi = overlay.createItem(i);
                                System.out.println("listing when more value is  "+ arrayList.get(i).getUnitstotal());
                                if(overlay!=null)
                                {
                                    overlay.addItem(oi);
                                    //overlay.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
                                }

                            }
                        }
```

//draw method for text draw over bubbles

```
                @Override
     public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when )    
    {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, false);



        arrayList1 = arrayList;
        for (int index = 0; index < items.size(); index++)
          {
            OverlayItem item = items.get(index);
            GeoPoint point = item.getPoint();
            Point ptScreenCoord = new Point();
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(point, ptScreenCoord);
            //Paint
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);  
            paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
            paint.setTypeface((Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD)));
            paint.setTextSize(20);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            paint.setFilterBitmap(false);//true
            if(arrayList.get(index).getUnitstotal().equalsIgnoreCase("1"))                  
                canvas.drawText("", ptScreenCoord.x, ptScreenCoord.y-20,paint);
            else
            {

                  canvas.drawText(arrayList.get(index).getUnitstotal().toString(), ptScreenCoord.x, ptScreenCoord.y-40, paint); 
            }

        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: are you using the correct Map API Key ?

Comment: I am generating new API key ,then see..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641197/android-app-google-maps-showing-grey-tiles-and-not-map

Comment: Please check the zoom level and the center point:

mapView.getController().setZoom(2); 
getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(0, 0));

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show a map in an Android mapactivity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097594/how-to-show-a-map-in-an-android-mapactivity)

Answer (score 0):

Most Probably you havent fetched google map api key, please fetch it according to the instructions on following link, and then try:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey